# Cosmos DB Graph Edge partitioning

Tags: azure, graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Cosmos DB has pre-announced general availability of Gremlin (Graph API). Probably by the end of 2017 it will get out of preview, so we might consider it stable enough for production. That brings me to the following:

We are designing a system with an estimated user-base up to 100 million users. Each user will have some documents in Cosmos to store user-related data, those documents are partitioned on the id of the user (a Guid). So when estimations come true we will end up with at least 100 million partitions, each containing a bunch of documents.

Not only will we store user-related data but also interrelated data (relationships) between users. On paper Cosmos should be very well suited for these kinds of scenarios, utilizing it cross-api with Document API for normal data and Graph API purely for the relationships.

An example of one of these relationships is a Follow. For instance `UserX` can Follow `UserY`. To realize this relationship, we created a Gremlin query that creates an `Edge`:

```
    g.V().hasId('{userX.Id}').has('pkey','{userX.Partition}')
    .addE('follow').to(g.V().hasId('{userY.Id}').has('pkey','{userY.Partition}'))
```

The resulting `Edge` automatically gets assigned to the partition of `UserX`, because `UserX` is the out-vertex.

When querying on outgoing edges (all the users that `UserX` is following), all is fine and well because the query is limited to the partition for `UserX`.

```
    g.V().hasId('{userX.Id}').has('pkey','{userX.Partition}').outE('follow').inV()
```

However when inverting the query (find all followers of `UserY`), looking for incoming edges, the situation changes - to my knowledge this will result in a full cross-partition query:

```
    g.V().hasId('{userY.Id}').has('pkey','{userY.Partition}').inE('follow').outV()
```

In my opinion a full cross-partition query with 100 million partitions is unacceptable.

I have tried putting the `Edge` between `UserX` and `UserY` inside its own partition, but the Graph API does not let me do this. (*Edit: Changed Cosmos to Graph API*)

Now I have come to the point of implementing a pair of edges between `UserX` and `UserY`, one outgoing `Edge` for `UserX` and one outgoing `Edge` for `UserY`, trying to keep them in-sync. All this in order to optimize the speed of my queries, but also introducing more work to achieve eventual consistency.

Then again I am wondering if the Graph API is really up to these kinds of scenario's - or I am really missing on something here?

Comment: This is indeed a limitation of how Cosmo's graph functionality is implemented. Creating two edges to support bi-directional querying could help your performance but obviously you need to build in application logic to ensure that both edges are always successfully created. There is no support for transactions or ACID when operating on documents between partitions

Comment: @JesseCarter Thanks for the answer. Actually it is the Graph API that is implemented this way, if we start buzzing around directly with the REST interface of Cosmos we can get more out of it. Right now I am looking into creating Vertices and Edges through UDFs to achieve some form of transactions...

Comment: @cldons that was a very good question that i was searching for an answer to it and you explained it so well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will start by clearing a slight misconception you have regarding CosmosDB partitioning. 100 Million users doesn’t mean 100 million partitions. They simply mean 100 million partition keys. When you create a cosmos dB graph it starts with 10 physical partitions ( this is starting default which can be changed upon request), and then scales automatically as data grows.

In this case 100 million users will be distributed among 10 physical partitions. Hence the full cross partition query will hit on 10 physical partition.  Also note that these partitions will be hit in parallel, so the expected latency would be similar to hitting one partition, unless operation is similar to aggregates in nature.

Comment: @JayanteMondal Thanks for the answer - unfortunately it's not totally what I hoped for. I've read the official documentation about Cosmos partitioning again and noticed that there is no clear distinction between logical and physical partitioning throughout the article. Am I right on the idea that if I use a pair of Edges (in & out) in order to define a relationship, the RUs spent querying will be a lot less than only defining an out Edge and querying for incoming?

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic partitioning dilemma, not unique to Cosmos/Graph.

If your usage pattern is lots of queries with small scope then cross-partition is bad.   If it is returning large data sets then cross-partition overhead is probably insignificant against the benefits of parallelism.   Unless you have a constant high volume of queries then I think the cross-partition overhead is overstated (MS seem to think everyone is building the next Facebook on Cosmos).

In the OP case you can optimise for x follows y, or x is followed by y, or both by having an edge each way.   Note that RUs are reserved on a per partition basis (i.e. total RU / number of partitions) so to use them efficiently you need either high volume, evenly distributed, single partition queries or queries that span multiple partitions.